# Quasar UI Q-Date picker. How do I get a q-input to accept another date format and update the model value in q-date?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, quasar

I have a quasar q-date with q-input. If I just leave the model it works fine. However, I want to display the date in the q-input according to user's locale. I also get the date from an API as an ISO string so need to convert first before I can use it.

I want user to be able to type into the q-input or alternatively use the date picker.

I have tried all sorts of computed props/watcher/emits but just can't seem to get it to work.

I can get the correctly formatted date and can update the model using date picker. I cannot do anything with the q-input date though. Because it's updating as soon as I input it messes up the date. It's like I need a debounce or something?

Ot maybe there's a much simpler way of dealing with dates?

Here's my current attempt:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-input
      v-model="formattedDate"
      :mask="dateMask"
      :hint="dateFormat + ' ' + clientLocale"
    >
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
          <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
            <q-date v-model="rawDate" :mask="dateFormat" today-btn>
              <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
              </div>
            </q-date>
          </q-popup-proxy>
        </q-icon>
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { date } from "quasar";

//Incoming date. Normally from API.
const rawDate = ref("2023-08-09T03:42:24.957Z");

//Get client locale for date formatting
const clientLocale = navigator.language;
const dateFormat = useGetLocaleDateFormat();

//Make a mask for the q-input in the form of ##-##-#### or whatever locale. Works fine.
const dateMask = dateFormat.replace(/[DMY]/g, "#");

//Format the date for display in the q-input.
const formattedDate = computed({
  get() {
    console.log(
      "formatted date",
      date.formatDate(new Date(rawDate.value), dateFormat)
    );
    return date.formatDate(new Date(rawDate.value), dateFormat);
  },
  set(newValue) {
    console.log("new value", new Date(newValue).toISOString());
    //Always return an ISO String
    rawDate.value = new Date(newValue).toISOString();
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: `rawDate` must be a computed property with getter and setter. Setter will be used by QDate when choosing a date from the calendar. Getter will use `formattedDate` and transform it into `YYYY-MM-DD` which is suitable for QDate input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out after too many hours.

Here's the revised code:

```
<template>
  <q-input class="fit" v-model="formattedDate" :mask="dateMask" id="date-input">
    <template v-slot:prepend>
      <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
        <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
          <q-date v-model="formattedDate" :mask="dateFormat" today-btn>
            <div class="row items-center justify-end">
              <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
            </div>
          </q-date>
        </q-popup-proxy>
      </q-icon>
    </template>
  </q-input>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { date } from "quasar";

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

//Get client locale for date formatting
const clientLocale = navigator.language;
const dateFormat = useGetLocaleDateFormat();

//Make a mask for the q-input in the form of ##-##-#### or whatever locale.
const dateMask = dateFormat.replace(/[DMY]/g, "#");

//Format the date for display in the q-input.
const formattedDate = ref(
  date.formatDate(new Date(props.modelValue), dateFormat)
);

//Watchers to emit the updated date when changed.
watch(formattedDate, (newDateValue) => {
  //construct new date ISO string from the formattedDate.
  const newDate = date.extractDate(newDateValue, dateFormat);
  //convert to iso string
  const updatedDate = newDate.toISOString();
  emit("update:modelValue", updatedDate);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is nuts really.  You would think this functionality would be built in to q-date.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: adding mask="DD/MM/YYYY" to q-date and mask="##/##/####" to q-input:

```
<q-input
  v-model="newDate.from"
  mask="##/##/####"
 >
   <template v-slot:append>
     <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
       <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
         <q-date v-model="newDate.from" mask="DD/MM/YYYY">
           <div class="row items-center justify-end">
             <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
            </div>
           </q-date>
          </q-popup-proxy>
         </q-icon>
        </template>
       </q-input>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<q-input
            id="create-user-page-form-end-validity-date"
            outlined
            dense
            rounded
            no-error-icon
            hide-bottom-space
            v-model="userCreation.endValidity"
            :rules="dateEndValidityRule"
            :placeholder="$t('user_creation_page.date_end_validity')"
          >
            <template v-slot:prepend>
              <q-icon
                name="event"
                class="cursor-pointer"
              >
                <q-popup-proxy
                  cover
                  transition-show="scale"
                  transition-hide="scale"
                >
                  <q-date
                    v-model="userCreation.endValidity"
                    years-in-month-view
                    mask="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
               
                  >
                    <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                      <q-btn
                        v-close-popup
                        label="Close"
                        color="primary"
                        flat
                      />
                    </div>
                  </q-date>
                </q-popup-proxy>
              </q-icon>
            </template>
          </q-input>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).